# Strange output after date conversion in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I am getting data from an API. The date attached to each object comes in this format:

> Timestamp is the date and time of an
>   event in UTC time. This is expressed
>   as a specific number of milliseconds
>   since the standard base "epoch" of:
>   January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

I am trying to convert this into a different date format in Ruby.

CODE

```
objects.each do |obj|
  p "object"
  p obj.created
  p Time.at(obj.created)
end
```

OUTPUT

```
"object"
1308886130000
43446-12-14 10:33:20 +1000
"object"
1308886104000
43446-12-14 03:20:00 +1000
"object"
1308801345000
43444-04-07 03:10:00 +1000
```

The years are obviously incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Time.at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000334) function expects time since the epoch in seconds. You're giving it milliseconds, so the calculation is way off.

Divide that timestamp by 1000.